# Separating English text and non-English Text from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have a .csv file and I want to separate Non-English Text and English Text in two different files. Below is the code, I tried:

```
  import string
  def isEnglish(s):
      return s.translate(None, string.punctuation).isalnum()
  file=open('File1.csv','r',encoding='UTF-8')
  outfile1=open('Eng.csv','w', encoding='utf-8')
  outfile2=open('Noneng.csv','w', encoding='utf-8')
  for line in file.readlines():
       r = isEnglish(line)
       if r:
          outfile1.write(line+"\n")
       else:
          outfile2.write(line+"\n")
```

The code is not producing the desired result. There is repetitive English text in both the files. I have attached a snapshot of one output file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by non-english text?  You want only ASCII?  What about "naïve" or "resumé"?  Emoji?

Comment: the non-English text means a language other than English. No problem in retaining Latin characters and emojis. In fact, I want to retain emojis and Latin characters.

Comment: How do you plan to identify English from non-English? What languages are options here?

Comment: I tried to use detect_language() of TextBlob library but it raised error after few lines. Then I tried the above code. All languages such as Japanese, Portuguese, French, Spanish, Urdu, Tamil and Telugu are there in the file

Comment: Str.translate is not for translating strings into a different human language automatically. Please read the documentation for that function, it won't help you here at all

Comment: This is the project you want for detecting the human language of some text https://github.com/Elizafox/cld3

Comment: Can you have multiple languages in the same row?

Comment: No, such case doesn't exist in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to mention the code produces this result:

```
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Would you please Read The Fine Manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

The documentation offers a pretty big hint
that you should call `str.maketrans( ... )`
to create the desired translation map.
This will help you identify input strings that are
strictly alphanumeric.

```
translation_table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
```

Comment: This did not communicate what you wanted it to communicate: "Code is not producing desired result." Please tell us (1.) what result the code produced, and (2.) the desired result. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Both files are having English texts and each text is repeating n number of times in both the files. When I opened files in notepad++, it shows the message as "File is too big to be opened". The reason is the repetition of the same text in the two files.